# Can I import an UPDATED PARTITION right after I DROP the old one?

Tags: pyspark, parquet, clickhouse

I have a table named `transactions` (alias `txs` for short) that contains 15 million rows `PARTITIONED BY txs.year` for data accumulated over last 10-years (approx. 1 to 1.5-million rows/year). Source of this data is a MySQL database and the only data that changes is the data for `current year`. My strategy is to setup a daily CRON job that exports all records for `current year` in a compressed CSV format (i.e. `20XX-txs.csv.gz`) and then use AWS Glue/PySpark to convert it to `snappy.parquet` format `PARTITIONED BY txs.year`.

I've read that you can easily `DROP PARTITIONS` with ClickHouse ([reference](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/alter/partition/)). One thing throws me off without any further explanation. Their documentation states:

> Deletes the specified partition from the table. This query tags  the
> partition as inactive and *deletes data completely, approximately in
> 10 minutes*.

What I am wondering is :

1. Where does the *10 minutes* part come in? From my tests, I see the partition gone immediately.
2. Can I `INSERT` updated data from the newly created `snappy.parquet` partition immediately after `DROPPING` the stale partition for `current_year` or do I have to wait the full *10 minutes* prior to doing so?

Example use case:

```sh
# STEP 1: Get updated data for current_year
# -----------------------------------------
$ wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/xxx.xxx/2021-txs.snappy.parquet

# STEP 2: Drop existing PARTITION for current_year
# -----------------------------------------
$ clickhouse-client --query="ALTER TABLE txs DROP PARTITION '2021'"

# STEP 3: INSERT updated data for current_year into the table
# -----------------------------------------
$ cat 2021-txs.snappy.parquet | clickhouse-client --query="INSERT INTO txs FORMAT Parquet"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's irrelevant in your use-case.

It's about removing data from disk not about a table. (Users sometimes are worrying about disk freeing)

> This query tags the partition as inactive
> and deletes data completely, approximately in 10 minutes.

That is funny side-effect of merges.

Active parts removed immediately with DROP PARTITION but inactive are not.

```
create table t(a Int64) Engine=MergeTree order by a; 
insert into t values (1);
select name, active from system.parts where table = 't';
┌─name──────┬─active─┐
│ all_1_1_0 │      1 │
└───────────┴────────┘

optimize table t final;
-- forced merge produced the new part all_1_1_1 (active) and left the old 
-- part all_1_1_0 (inactive). 

select name, active from system.parts where table = 't';
┌─name──────┬─active─┐
│ all_1_1_0 │      0 │
│ all_1_1_1 │      1 │
└───────────┴────────┘

alter table t drop partition tuple();  -- DATA IS DROPPED
-- but only active parts

select count() from t;
┌─count()─┐
│       0 │
└─────────┘ 

-- but inactive parts are still in waiting for 
-- background process to drop them after 8 minutes inactivity
select name, active from system.parts where table = 't';
┌─name──────┬─active─┐
│ all_1_1_0 │      0 │
└───────────┴────────┘

ls -1 /var/lib/clickhouse/data/default/t/
all_1_1_0
detached
format_version.txt
```

10 - minutes, actually 8 (480s) is controlled by merge_tree setting old_parts_lifetime

google translate: *Inactive parts are not deleted immediately, because when writing a new chunk, `fsync` is not called, i.e. for some time the new piece is located only in the server's RAM (OS cache). So if the server is rebooted spontaneously, new just merged parts can be lost or damaged. Then ClickHouse during the startup process is checking the integrity of the parts, can detect a problem, return the inactive parts to the active list, and later merge them again. Then the broken parts is renamed (the prefix broken is added) and moved to the detached folder. If the integrity check detects no problems in the merged chunk, then the original inactive chunks are renamed (prefix ignored is added) and moved to the detached folder.*

Comment: Thank you Denny. That helps a lot in understanding the inner-workings.