# How correctly drop partition in clickhouse to write data immediately after deletion

Tags: clickhouse

I have distributed table ('rec') and local table ('rec_local') in clickhouse.
Every day we transfer data from hive to clickhouse(using Airflow). Ussualy everything is fine, but sometimes we need to restart dag.

Flow in dag is:
Check patition -> if it is exist -> delete partition -> transfer data
if it is not exist -> transfer data

To delete data we used:
"""ALTER TABLE rec ON CLUSTER cluster DROP PARTITION '{self._ch_day_partition}'"""
But due asynchronous deleting part of our data were dropped during inserting

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mkris.png)

So we want to use DETACH PARTITION -> DROP DETACHED PARTITION -> INSERT:

1. """ALTER TABLE rec ON CLUSTER cluster
   DETACH PARTITION '{self._ch_day_partition}'
   """
2. """ALTER TABLE rec ON CLUSTER cluster
   DROP DETACHED PARTITION '{self._ch_day_partition}'
   """

Is it safety way to drop partition in clickhouse to write data immediately after deletion?

thanks for help

we had:
"""ALTER TABLE rec ON CLUSTER cluster DROP PARTITION '{self._ch_day_partition}'"""

we want to use:

1. """ALTER TABLE rec ON CLUSTER cluster
   DETACH PARTITION '{self._ch_day_partition}'
   """
2. """ALTER TABLE rec ON CLUSTER cluster
   DROP DETACHED PARTITION '{self._ch_day_partition}'
   """

Comment: try to poll 
`system.distributed_ddl_queue` for your `ALTER TABLE ... DROP` query

Comment: found an answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65702378/can-i-import-an-updated-partition-right-after-i-drop-the-old-one